# PHP/MySQL not displaying all results

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me figure out what's my issue?
I'm having a problem with displaying some results from my database.
I'm trying to display all the settings of a user by looking them up on a lookup table but the results are skipping every other variable.
**For example it is displaying (wrong):**

```
relationship_status : In a relationship<br>
eye_color : green<br>
religion : christian (catholic)<br>
body_type : average<br>
education : don't say<br>
looking_for : don't say<br>
drinker : don't say<br>
```

**It should display (correct):**

```
orientation : straight<br>
relationship_status : In a relationship<br>
hair_color : black<br>
eye_color : green<br>
ethnicity : black<br>
religion : christian (catholic)<br>
politics : liberal<br>
body_type : average<br>
children : don't say<br>
education : don't say<br>
income : don't say<br>
looking_for : don't say<br>
smoker : don't say<br>
drinker : don't say<br>
```

I have checked my variables in the `$lookup_table_names` array and they are all correct.
My mysql syntax is correct, I can't figure out why it's skipping results.

```
$lookup_table_names = array('orientation'=>$orientation,'relationship_status'=> $status,'hair_color'=>$hair_color,
                            'eye_color'=>$eye_color,'ethnicity'=>$ethnicity,'religion'=>$religion,
                            'politics'=>$politics,'body_type'=>$body_type,'children'=>$children,'education'=>$education,
                            'income'=>$income,'looking_for'=>$looking_for,'smoker'=>$smoker,'drinker'=>$drinker
);

foreach ($lookup_table_names as $tablename => $val) {
    $query = "SELECT value FROM lookup_".$tablename." WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";

    if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($query)){
        $stmt -> bind_param('i',$val);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($myvalue);
        $stmt -> fetch();
        echo '<br><br>'.$tablename.' : '.$myvalue.'<br><br>';
    }else{
        printf($stmt->error);
    }
}
```

This is what I am getting.
 If I had to guess I would say it has to do with the MySQL statements executing too fast?
[image]

Comment: *MySQL statements executing too fast*? Interesting thought, but no. Codes are executed in sequence.

Comment: another reason i use node.js...

Comment: try error_reporting(E_ERROR); at the top.

Comment: Excellent - sorry, just accidentally deleted my comment so now the comment list looks weird! :)

Comment: @danielpsc I added $stmt->close(); after fetch() like you said. Thanks a lot, it was driving me insane!